# Can arguments be referenced in JavaScript using ColdFusion syntax?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

In ColdFusion, if you want to reference

```
<cfargument name="x">
```

then you say:

```
arguments.x
```

In JavaScript, if you have a function:

```
var myFunction = function(x) {
```

then, is there a way to explicitly reference the arguments scope like maybe:

```
arguments[0].x
```

or something so that you're scoping everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve the same functionality by using the arguments variable, as it holds no information on parameter names. To circumvent this, you could switch from using multiple parameters to one compound parameter object that holds actual parameter values in  its members.

```
<script>
   function abc(params) {
    var x = params.x;
     var y = params["y"];
  }

   abc( { x: 10, y: "hello" });
</script>
```

This way however you lose some of the readability of the code  at the function signature, plus you must provide param names on the calling side.

Comment: Oh, I like it.  Hey!  Could I then use: arguments[0].params.x?

Comment: You know Peter, that was a VERY GOOD explanation.

Comment: Then I think that's the syntax that I'll use.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the `arguments` pseudo-variable, but the arguments are indexed by number, not by name. It's a good idea to avoid messing with `arguments` directly; a common idiom is to convert it to a real array:

```
var args = Array.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

Comment: I've been studying JavaScript for over a year and can't remember seeing this common idiom.  Man, I gotta hit the books more!

Comment: So would I then reference it as args["x"] maybe?

Comment: @Pointy, why not just reference directly i.e. `arguments[0]`?

Comment: I believed you mean: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);`, or `Array.slice(arguments, 0)` (that is a generic and it's supported by Firefox only AFAIK).

Comment: It's a common idiom only when you need a real array that contains the arguments given. If you want just to iterate or access to them by index, `splice` is not necessary.

Comment: @ZER0 yes that's true, but the `arguments` variable is best thought of as "toxic"; it was sort-of a design mistake. That's why avoiding it is prudent.  (In my personal opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. You can explicitly use `x` or `arguments[0]` but nothing more. Unless, as pointed out from others, you pass an object.